# Rearranging text file based on the arrangement of another txt file? (python)

Tags: python, txt

I have two txt files, num.txt and wds.txt. num.txt only contains numbers and looks like the following:

60

45

60

60

32

...

There is one number per line in this file.

The other txt file, wds.txt, contains phrases (only words) per line, like the following.

i like to eat candy

and pizza

i also like to

code

....

I want to rearrange num.txt based on the wds.txt by placing numbers that occur back to back in num.txt into one line **based on the number of words in wds.txt in that line.**

So, if there are 5 words in wds.txt on line 1, then the first 5 numbers in num.txt should be on line 1 in the file. If there are 3 words in wds.txt on line 2, then the second set of 3 words in num.txt should be on line to in num.txt.

wds.txt should not be changed. num.txt should look like the following in the end:

60 45 60 60 32

45 60
...

with the first line corresponding to "i like to eat candy." There are 5 numbers in the first line because there are 5 words in the first line in wds.txt.

The txt files differ, so I need to find the number of words (separated by spaces) in wds.txt and rearrange num.txt accordingly.

```
merge = (df['ID'] != df['ID'].shift()).cumsum().rename('grp')
df1 = df.groupby(['ID', merge], sort=False)['I']\
      .agg(' '.join).reset_index().drop('grp', axis=1)
```

But, this only rearranges num.txt based on consecutive numbers.

Comment: maybe use normal `for`-loop and for every line get `numbers[ :len(words_in_line) ]` and next slice it `numbers = numbers[ len(words_in_line): ]` to use shorter `numbers` with next line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe read all data as normal lists

```
numbers = [60,45,60,60,32,45,60,73,23,14,37]
lines = ['i like to eat candy', 'and pizza', 'i also like to']
```

And then use normal `for`-loop to count words in every line and get `numbers[ :count ]` and slice this list `number = numbers[ count: ]` to use shorter `numbes` with next lines.

```
numbers = [60,45,60,60,32,45,60,73,23,14,37]

lines = ['i like to eat candy', 'and pizza', 'i also like to']

for line in lines:
    count = len(line.split(' '))
    print(numbers[:count], line)
    numbers = numbers[1:]
    #numbers = numbers[count:]
```

Result

```
[60, 45, 60, 60, 32] i like to eat candy
[45, 60] and pizza
[60, 60, 32, 45] i also like to
```

And you have to only write `numbers[:count]` to file instead of `print()`.

```
fh.write( " ".join(str(x) for x in numbers[:count]) + "\n" )
```